# ssd usage 100% and pc very slow

Tags: ssd

i have a problem with my SSD, its active time is always 100%, start-up takes long to load and everything is laggy and doesn't respond. it goes to 0 when I don't do anything or after one or two hours of the pc lagging. I searched for the problem but nothing seemed to solve it. i looked on resource monitor to see what uses it so much but only System MoUsoCoreWorker and Chrome.
thanks.

Comment: "it's always 100%" - [Edit] your question to clarify this statement.  What exactly is 100%?

Comment: Sounds like the SSD is full, use clean manager to free up some space.

Comment: i edited the post

Comment: How old is the SSD?

Comment: "I searched for the problem and nothing seemed to solve it". What did you try?